# Send object array to node/Parse to Json

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to send object array to node.
If i'm sending it without stringify, i'm getting an array with the same length that i sent, but empty  `(["", ""])`;

if i send it with `JSON.stringify` , this it the result:

`{'[{"itemNumber":"13544","currentShelf":"1A1","amount":"1","newShelf":"","actionType":"in","whareHouse":"Main"},{"itemNumber":"13544","currentShelf":"1B1","amount":"1","newShelf":"","actionType":"in", "whareHouse":"Main"}]': '' }`

This is how i'm sending it:

```
      for (var i=1; i<=m; i++){

            itemIdTemp= document.getElementById("itemIdShell"+i).value;
            shellTemp= document.getElementById("id_shell"+i).value.toUpperCase();
            newShellTemp= document.getElementById("id_shell_new"+i).value.toUpperCase();
            shellAmountTemp = document.getElementById("amountShell"+i).value;
            itemAmount=0;
            let itemData={
                        itemNumber:itemIdTemp,
                        currentShelf:shellTemp,
                        amount:shellAmountTemp,
                        newShell:newShellTemp,
                        actionType:direction,
                        whareHouse:"Main",
                        };
            console.log(itemData);
            itemsObject.push(itemData);

        }
        console.log(itemsObject);



        $.post('/itemShell/updateMulti', 
                    JSON.stringify(itemsObject),
                    function(data){  
                        console.log(data);
                    });
```

The object contain a string of the array and i can't get it.
I tried `Json.Parse()`, it won't work in this case.

any suggestions?

Comment: How do you send it?! This JSON is invalid, `JSON.stringify` wont produce this.

Comment: this is to outcome of the stringify to a normal object's array

Comment: Please provide relevant code that reproduces problem as in [mcve]

Comment: Your stringifyed object string is not valid , JSON format does not use single quote

Comment: i changed it, still same result

Comment: 'if i send it with "JSON.stringify" , this it the result: `{'[{"itemNumber":"13544",...`' - Where are you seeing that object? It looks to me like the server is expecting something like `itemNumber=13544&currentShelf=1A1&...`. It has code for parsing strings like that, and has tried to run it on your JSON string. Can we see your server code please?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example code

```
const jsObjectArray = [
  {name: "Homer", age:56 },
  {name: "Marge", age:50 },
];
const buf = JSON.stringify(jsObjectArray);
console.log("Stringified object: "+buf);
//
// Now convert it back to an object
//
const newObject = JSON.parse(buf);
console.log("Reconstituted object: "+newObject);
```

It's in this codepen too:

https://codepen.io/mikkel/pen/KRayye

Comment: it won't  with node.. the data is being send in a another type as  i wrote

Comment: If you try this tester, you'll see that it does work https://repl.it/repls/CarefreeShowyCoderesource

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
It must be declare as JSON type when post to Node, so u need to use ajax:

```
                $.ajax({
                        url: '/itemShell/updateMulti',
                        type:"POST",
                        data:JSON.stringify(dataTosend),
                        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType:"json",
                        success: function(){}
                   }
```

and i also change it to object type like this:

```
            dataToSend={dataArr:itemsObject}
```

So in node it's appearing as array

Answer (score -1):

My Guy work a little bit on the string before sending it

First get the string the stringify is returning

```
var json_string = JSON.stringify(itemsObject);

var string = json_string.replace("'", "\'");

string = '{\'[{"itemNumber":"13544","currentShelf":"1A1","amount":"1",
"newShelf":"","actionType":"in","whareHouse":"Main"},
{"itemNumber":"13544","currentShelf":"1B1","amount":"1",
"newShelf":"","actionType":"in", "whareHouse":"Main"}]\': \'\' }';

first_str = string.split("': ");  // remove the last useless chars

second  = first_str[0].substring(2, first_str[0].length);  // remove the first two chars

$.post('/itemShell/updateMulti', second,
                function(data){  
                    console.log(data);
                });
```

the second should have the correct string.

GOODLUCK

Comment: I think OP means that's what the data looks like on the server. And they haven't said they have access to the server code. Besides, it's a bit silly to send data in such a weird format, just because you can't figure out how to do it a sensible way.

Comment: Whats on the server, did you read his code above he has access to all the variables used here. There is nothing wierd here just js splits.

Comment: I think `string` only appears on the server, because I have a conjecture for how this happened (see my comment on the question). They haven't said much about the server - they can evidently debug, but not necessarily change the code. Your code will fail if there's no space after the `':`, or if `string` has whitespace before `[`, or if `': ` appears inside a JSON string literal (e.g. `"currentShelf":"': '"`). I admit there probably isn't a nice way of doing this. But if they're sloppy enough to rely on strings like this then they probably don't have a clearly defined interface, which is bad.

Comment: The result displaying on the server is as a result of the JSON.strigify method like @gabibrk said. So we can work on it. The solution to this is always going to be the same for this since we are only escaping the quotes that gabibrk has confirmed its the result of the JSON.strigify. Besides its only a work around

Comment: I'm OK with the json string. It's the pointless extra stuff around it that I'm complaining about. "The solution to this is always going to be the same..." If you're saying it's safe to assume that the exact structure of the extra stuff won't change, then you _might_ be right, but it's better to avoid this altogether. I don't know exactly how the string was generated, OP probably understands even less, and for all we know it could be affected by an upgrade to the server (or a string containing `': `). We shouldn't have to resort to a workaround, we can do better than that.

Comment: I've just realised that `string` is a string because you stringified it, even though you wanted to go in the opposite direction. If you must use `itemsObject`, why not just do `second = Object.keys(itemsObject)[0];`?

Comment: That doesn't mean all answers are equally good. If you have a choice between The Right Answer and a workaround, you choose The Right Answer.